# IOS handling opened urls swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, instagram

I am new in IOS, and I stocked with integration Instagram into my app.

```
@IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!


    var UrlInsta = "https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=my_id&redirect_uri=Locations://test&response_type=code";

func loadInstaSite(){
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: UrlInsta);
        let requestSite = NSURLRequest(URL:  requestURL);

        WebView.loadRequest(requestSite);

        NSLog("%d" , 1);

    }
```

This is my `ViewController.swift`
WebView opens fine. 
When user clicks *Authorise my app and go to the Locations://test*, my app open again my main view with `web view`.
How to handle url when my app is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let url = "http://apple.com"
```

Change the viewDidLoad method to

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

[Here is an example with source code](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/webview-tutorial-in-ios8-with-swift)

You can also try this code by apple

Asks the delegate to open a resource identified by URL.
Declaration

```
Swift

optional func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                  openURL url: NSURL,
        sourceApplication sourceApplication: String,
               annotation annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool

Objective-C

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
```

[Here is the more explanation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)